# Batch File: Finding File type, move file, add owner details

Tags: batch-file, networking

**What I've done so far-**
I've created a script that will be able to scan a remote computer for a `.pst` file and move it to a certain path.

**What I am looking for-**
I am looking at appending this so i can put details on the file that was transferred, IE A text file in the same directory, or copying the parent folder.

***Breakdown-**
I understand that I am able to look at the file properties and see who the file belongs to. Just looking to print those details- the owner property and its value, if possible, to a `.txt` file in the same folder.

The Code:

```
@echo off 
set startpath=C:\ 
set destpath=\Domaincontroller.testnet.com\c$\TEST 
mkdir %destpath% 2>nul
for /d %%T in (pst,rdp) do call :copyfile %%T 

goto end

:copyfile

set type=%1 
echo C R H Information Systems, Working on %type% file type, Moving .PST  To Destination...
for /f "tokens=" %%A in ('dir %startpath%.%type% /b /s') do echo %%A & xcopy /d /y "%%A" "%destpath%"***

:end
```

Thank You for any help

Comment: Look at the help for the DIR command.  Specifically the `/Q` option.

Comment: And redirect it to a text file. `dir /q c:\windows\win.ini > text.txt`

Comment: Thank you all. I will let you know how this turns out on Monday.